# NoClassDefFoundError when running program

Tags: java, compilation, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem that I know has been asked a lot on here, but all of the posts I've found before (and I've found a lot of them) aren't working for me.

I have a basic Java program that I've uploaded to a server. When I log into the server via SSH, the .java file is in my home directory. I compile it on the server and confirm that the .class file is generated.

But when I try to run the program using

```
java <program name>
```

it gives me the error.

What have I tried?

- Creating a subdirectory with both files in it
- Invoking the program with the package name (i.e. java packagename.programname)
- Compiling it off of the server and then transferring both on
- Explicitly set the class path using -cp

What's really weird is that I took another program and was able to compile and run it without a problem, even though it's essentially the same program (I copied and pasted portions into mine).

I can include parts of the code here if needed, though I'll need to be told exactly which parts are needed, as there are quite a few lines.

Comment: Most of the times NoClassDefErrors are due to classpath issues, it seems required classes/jar files are not in path.

Comment: I don't think its good idea to keep `.java` files on server. Why not `.jar` ?

Comment: When I tried the .jar earlier, the program would run but wouldn't execute portions properly. So that's why I moved to just executing the java file on the server. 

I don't know why the required class files wouldn't be there. They're generated when I run javac, so unless that isn't working right, I don't think that's it.

Comment: What I would do is create an example as simple as possible that can reproduce this issue then let us look at the code and the command you're using to run it.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I think I'm just going to use the `.jar` way for now. Which means another problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JWhich](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwhich) when you encounter classpath issues or classes/jar file version inconsistencies.